# Change country in macro sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Everytime i chenge the country during a macro recording the recording stops and I loose the macro. How can I do a macro to change the country of my spreadsheet after i have recorded some actions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The macro recorder of Google Sheets isn't able to record all the steps done on the Google Sheets user interface. It can't record the clicks done on menus that doesn't make a change to a sheet or cell.

You might edit the recorded macro to add the missing steps, i.e. to change the spreadsheet country, (Google Apps Scripts docs call this setting *locale*) you might add the following:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreasheet().setSpreadsheetLocale(locale)
```

`locale` should be locale code to use, i.e. 'en', 'fr', etc.

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#setspreadsheetlocalelocale